# accessibility insights report checkmarks

Tags: accessibility-insights

On the Assessment report, there are a different number of empty dots (for lack of better word) next to each line item, which then afterwards have a checkmark or "x". Why a different quantity for each line item and when checkmarks and "x", what do they specifically represent? For instance, does the checker only check for Keyboard access in 6 ways or in 6 areas? And only check for Landmarks three times, and page navigation three times?[screenshot of assessment report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzeml.png)
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using Accessibility Insights! The empty dots/circles you see on the Overview page of Assessment correspond to the number of requirements per test. Each test has a different number of requirements. For example, the Keyboard test has 6 requirements, which you can see when you select/expand "Keyboard" in the left navigation bar, while the Landmarks test has 3 requirements. From the expanded test in the left navigation bar, you may select each requirement to find How to test info and add failure instances, if needed. Once you complete a requirement (mark it as pass or fail + add failure instances), the empty dots will update to show a green check (pass) or red x (fail). This way, you are able to quickly see your progress from the Overview page.